# How to recover previous session by default in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Sometimes I shutdown my computer with Firefox browser open.  When I open the browser again, sometimes it opens with the option to recover last session tabs, and sometimes I have to go the chronology tab and "recover last session".

Is there a way to automatically always recover the last session and reopen all tabs (no matter whether it crashed the previous session or ended accidentally)?

Comment: Assuming you're on Windows, you really should try to shut down properly instead of powering off! You might get lost or corrupted data otherwise.

Comment: @BoffinbraiN Luckily I use Linux, anyway shutting down is done properly, but when is done with the browser open then it does not recover at the next session.

Comment: How odd. Do your other programs get closed correctly? I wonder if Firefox isn't getting SIGTERM, or it's just taking too long to exit.

Comment: I stumbled on this old question and see it never got an answer.  Are you referring to having Firefox start with the windows and tabs as they existed in the last session (a setting in preferences), or forcing the recover session dialog?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am referring to always recovering the last session and opening all tabs(no matter if it crashed the previous session or ended accidentally)

Comment: If you go to preferences, there's a setting for what to display when opening Firefox.  One choice is to always start with the tabs as they were open in the last session.  With that choice, if Firefox is aware that it crashed and isn't sure what was open at the time, it will automatically display the recovery screen showing the last stuff it remembers and ask you to confirm what you want.  If it isn't aware that it crashed, and/or isn't able to recover what it thinks might have been open, you're on your own to manually open what you want.  (cont'd)

Comment: Closing Firefox ensures that the current status is saved.  Firefox periodically saves, but if you don't exit gracefully, you risk unpredictable results when you open the next session.

Comment: @fixer1234 That did the trick, if you add your comments as an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to preferences (`Edit | Preferences` if you use the menu), there's a setting for what to display when opening Firefox (see `Startup` at the top of the `General` tab).  One choice from the pull-down menu is `Show windows and tabs from last time`.

With that choice, if Firefox is aware that it crashed or closed unexpectedly and isn't sure what was open at the time, it will automatically display the recovery screen showing the last stuff it remembers and ask you to confirm what you want. If it isn't aware that it crashed, and/or isn't able to recover what it thinks might have been open, you're on your own to manually open what you want.

Closing Firefox ensures that the current status is saved. Firefox periodically saves, but if you don't exit gracefully, you risk unpredictable results when you open the next session.  If Firefox is open when you close the OS, the OS will try to close it.  However, that isn't always reliable, especially if it takes a long time for Firefox to close or there is a lot of spawned activity.